# How do I schedule a build job in Jenkins from 8 PM to 6 AM?

Tags: jenkins, build, schedule

I need to schedule a Jenkins job for every minute from 8 PM to 6 AM. Is there any way to do this in Jenkins? The hour options are from 0-23: for example it will work with `* 6-20 * * *` (from 6 am to 8 pm) but I want something like `* 20-6 * * *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply more than one schedule for a Jenkins job.

```
0 0/1 20/1 ? * * *
0 0/1 0-6 ? * * *
```

The first expression will build the job every minute starting at minute `00`, every hour starting at `20:00`, of every day.
The second expression will build the job every minute starting at minute `00`, every hour between `00:00` and `06:00`, of every day.
In this way the job is scheduled to build every minute from 8 PM to 6 AM.